# fine-tuning huggingface DistilBERT for multi-class classification on custom dataset yields weird output shape on prediction

Tags: tensorflow2.0, predict, huggingface-transformers, distilbert

I'm trying to fine-tune huggingface's implementation of distilbert for multi-class classification (100 classes) on a custom dataset following the tutorial at https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html.

I'm doing so using Tensorflow, and fine-tuning in native tensorflow, that is, I use the following part of the tutorial for dataset creation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(train_encodings),
    train_labels
))
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(val_encodings),
    val_labels
))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(test_encodings),
    test_labels
))
```

And this one for fine-tuning:

```
from transformers import TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification
model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=model.compute_loss) # can also use any keras loss fn
model.fit(train_dataset.shuffle(1000).batch(16), epochs=3, batch_size=16)
```

Everything seems to go fine with fine-tuning, but when I try to predict on the test dataset using `model.predict(test_dataset)` as argument (with 2000 examples), the model seems to yield one prediction per token rather than one prediction per sequence...

That is, instead of getting an output of shape `(1, 2000, 100)`, I get an output of shape `(1, 1024000, 100)`, where 1024000 is the number of test examples (2000) * the sequence length (512).

Any hint on what's going on here?
(Sorry if this is naive, I'm very new to tensorflow).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I do not know why it's happening, as it should by the right code by looking at the tutorial.

But for me it worked to create numpy arrays out of the train_encodings and pass them directly to the fit method instead of creating the Dataset.

```
x1 = np.array(list(dict(train_encodings).values()))[0]
x2 = np.array(list(dict(train_encodings).values()))[1]
model.fit([x1,x2], train_labels, epochs=20)
```